# Laravel one to many relation delete request with guzzle

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-5, guzzle

I have two table, Book and Author, use one to many relation, Author as parent and Author as child. I used Guzzle for client request to Book and Author. But the problems when delete book table request from client app, getting error like this

```
    GuzzleHttp \ Exception \ ServerException (500)
Server error: `DELETE http://localhost:8080/api/author/4` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response: <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" /> <style> (truncated...)
```

and sometimes its success but parent table (Author) removed too.
And when i make request with postman all is work fine.

Its my code, thanks before.

**Book controller API**

```
<

?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Book;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;

/**
* 
*/
class BookController extends Controller

{
    public function allBook()
    {
        return response()->json(Book::all());
    }

    public function Book($id)
    {
        return response()->json(Book::find($id));
    }

    public function createBook(Request $request)
    {
        $book = Book::all();
        return Book::create($request->all());
    }

    public function updateBook($id, Request $request)
    {
        $book = Book::find($id);
        $book->update($request->all());

        return response()->json($book, 200);
    }

    public function deleteBook($id)
    {
        Book::find($id)->delete();
        return response('Book deleted', 200);
    }
}
```

**Book migration table**

```
 <?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateBooksTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('genres');
            $table->text('synopsis');
            $table->integer('author_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('author_id')->references('id')->on('authors')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {

    }
}
```

**Book Model**

```
  <?php

    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Book extends Model
    {
        protected $fillable =[
            'title','genres','synopsis','author_id'];

        public function author()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(Author::class);
        }
    }
```

and its **Book controller for request from client**

```
     public function deleteBook($id)
   {
    $client = New GuzzleHttpClient();
       $apiRequest = $client->request('DELETE','http://localhost:8080/api/book/'. $id);

       return redirect()->route('book.index')->with('response', 'Delete book successfully');

   }
```

Comment: It looks like Guzzle is receiving an error response of some type (it is truncated in your example). You should try to retrieve the actual error message and share it here.

Comment: maybe its what you mean, i get from laravel.log https://pastebin.com/nkSCPk19

Comment: Is there a reason you go about it with Guzzle instead of just calling the `Book::delete` method?

Comment: I think you got error from ambigous routes laravel. Try to send me a routes code

Comment: https://pastebin.com/U6gHRDJc its my route

Comment: oh, yes i make duplicate delete route in url, thankyou